# Salesforce managed package

Tags: managed-package

I had written my code in salesforce dev org and I want to do it managed package so when I try to do the namespace of managed package is not added to the code what I have to do search and replace it all or there is any other solution

Comment: No need to add the namespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Salesforce automatically prepends your namespace prefix, followed by two underscores (“__”), to all unique component names in your Salesforce organization. A unique package component is one that requires a name that no other component has within Salesforce, such as custom objects, custom fields, custom links, s-controls, and validation rules. For example, if your namespace prefix is abc and your managed package contains a custom object with the API name, Expense__c, use the API name abc__Expense__c to access this object using the API. The namespace prefix is displayed on all component detail pages.

> But if you are using javascript redirect or code then you need to
>   manually add your namespace in the javascript code

.